# Optimizing Arcpy Code to Generate Points Along a Line

Tags: arcpy, python

I have a line layer that shows roads across the country and I also have a table with road ID numbers that represent where potential stoplights would be placed. I have been able to use the shared ID numbers between the two feature classes to generate a point at the middle of a road segment and then add that point to a larger point layer. I am then able to calculate the geometry of the point layer and get lat long coordinates, which are essential to the analysis that I am doing. Here is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy, math, os, csv
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\dsala\Desktop\GISDATA\SE_Br.gdb"

outTBL = 'ComID_Info'
in_Tbl = 'C:\Users\dsala\Desktop\GISDATA\SE_Br.gdb\light_ComID'

Selection_field_polyline = "COMID"
Selection_field_table = "V2_ComID"
list_Lights_COMID = []
list_Road_COMID = []
cur_Tbl = arcpy.SearchCursor(in_Tbl)

for num in cur_Tbl:
    list_Plant_COMID.append(num.getValue(Selection_field_table)) 
    polyline_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('Road_network', "temp_Road_network")

cur_line = arcpy.SearchCursor(polyline_layer)
for row in cur_line:
    list_River_COMID.append(row.getValue(Selection_field_polyline))

S1 = set(list_Plant_COMID)
S2 = set(list_River_COMID)
intersect = S1.intersection(S2)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management('C:\Users\dsala\Desktop\GISDATA','Lights_pt', 'POINT', 'temp_points_layer')

for x in intersect:
layer1 = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute( polyline_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"COMID\" = {}".format(x))
Selection = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer1, "temp_road_location")
arcpy.GeneratePointsAlongLines_management(Selection, 'temp_points_layer', 'PERCENTAGE',  Percentage=50)

temp_pts_scur = arcpy.SearchCursor('temp_points_layer')
facilities_pts_icur = arcpy.InsertCursor('Lights_pts')
for pt in temp_pts_scur:
    facilities_pts_icur.insertRow(pt)

arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management ('Lights_pts', 'POINT_X_Y_Z_M')
```

I have been testing this code out on a few states, however when I expanded it nationwide it would never finish. It would spend too long trying to redraw the national road line layer every time my code selected a new line segment and would eventually crash. I am looking for a way to make this process more efficient. Ideally, there would be a workaround where I would not need to use the 'SelectLayerbyAttribute' Tool. I can't think of way to generate a new point layer that wouldn't involve selecting features to then use the 'GeneratePointsAlongaLine' tool.

Comment: Instead of using AddGeometryAttributes, you could try "Feature Vertices to Point" with the "mid" point type option. You want the Center of the line? Also, do you have an Attribute Index on COMID field?

Comment: In all cases, you should use the much faster cursors in the Data Access module: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/what-is-the-data-access-module-.htm